How to Display country abbreviation with time in flutter ( like for Dubai 7:55 PM DXB or for Pakistan 7:55 PM PKT )
I am getting timestamp from the backend and i wants to display the time the in this format
7:55 PM PKT

it should display the time and the user current country abbreviation how i can achieve in this in flutter

First, add the required packages to pubspec.yaml:
  intl: ^0.17.0
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0

for the question you asked, the Flutter code would look like this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TimeDisplay(
        timestamp: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TimeDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  final int timestamp;

  TimeDisplay({required this.timestamp});

  @override
  _TimeDisplayState createState() => _TimeDisplayState();
}

class _TimeDisplayState extends State<TimeDisplay> {
  String _formattedTime = '';
  String _timezoneAbbreviation = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getTimeZoneAndFormat();
  }

  Future<void> _getTimeZoneAndFormat() async {
    try {
      String timeZone = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
      DateTime dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(widget.timestamp * 1000, isUtc: true);
      DateTime localDateTime = dateTime.toLocal();
      String formattedTime = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(localDateTime);
      String timezoneAbbreviation = _getTimezoneAbbreviation(timeZone);

      setState(() {
        _formattedTime = formattedTime;
        _timezoneAbbreviation = timezoneAbbreviation;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _formattedTime = 'Error';
        _timezoneAbbreviation = '';
      });
    }
  }

  String _getTimezoneAbbreviation(String timezone) {
    if (timezone == 'Asia/Karachi') {
      return 'PKT';
    }
    return timezone.split('/').last;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Time Display'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _formattedTime.isEmpty
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Text(
                '$_formattedTime $_timezoneAbbreviation',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Just note that in this code I get the user's timezone in the _getTimeZoneAndFormat method, using FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone()If I may suggest, get this from the backend.
And in this method:
String _getTimezoneAbbreviation(String timezone) {
  if (timezone == 'Asia/Karachi') {
    return 'PKT';  // پاکستان (PKT)
  }

///add other timezones here...

  return timezone.split('/').last;  
}

You can add the time zones you want.
